# Is least squares optimisation in linear algebra different from how it is normally done in statistics?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, optimization

Previously, I learnt about the least squares regression line of $y$ against $x$ (which minimises the sum of the squares of the vertical residues) and that of $x$ against $y$ (which minimises the sum of the squares of the horizontal residues). I did not really learn to compute the equations of these lines but rather, just learnt them conceptually as well as how to compute their equations using a calculator.

As I learn introductory linear algebra in university currently, I once again revisit a similar topic, which is that of the least squares projections of vectors onto column spaces. Conceptually, the best fit line that is obtained from principally solving $A^T A x = A^T b$ is different from that in the previous cases of $y$ against $x$ and $x$ against $y$. This is because now we are trying to minimise the sum of the squares of the perpendicular residues. I would like to ask if there is a formal name given to a regression line obtained via this method?

Comment: There is a method called *major axis regression*, which does what you are asking in your final question. However, this is disconnected from what you are writing before that. Computing the regression line of $y$ against $x$ (or vice versa) indeed boils down to what you called least squares in linear algebra.

Comment: @Klaus So is solving $A^T A x = A^T b$ called major axis regression?

Comment: No, major axis regression is minimizing the squared orthogonal distances between the points and the line.

Comment: If you want to minimize the distance between the line and the datapoits, the correct choice is PCA (principal component analysis) using just one dimension

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, this is exactly the same thing, often called Linear Regression; it has many properties that are interesting in the two fields.

Long Answer: In fact, it can be proved that if $x$ satisfies $A^TAx=A^Tb$, then
$$x\in \arg \min_{z\in \mathbb R^n} \|Az-b\|_2,$$
that is, from an Algebraic point of view, $x$ is the projection of $b$ on the vector space generated by the coluns of $A$.

From the view of Statistics, one usually assumes that $b$ is a random vector generated by
$$(b)_i=(Ax)_i + (\varepsilon)_i\qquad \varepsilon_i \overset{i.i.d.}\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2).$$
In that context, one can prove that using the very same tecnique of solving $A^TAx=A^Tb$, we can find the best possible estimation of the true $x$ (maximum likelihood estimator).

Comment: But this line that we generate would neither be the least squares regression line of y on x or x on y right? Is there another name for it?